# Implicit Accessors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, accessor, ecmascript-harmony

In ColdFusion (a server-side language), it's possible to have CF generate any getters and setters in a class for you, like so:

```
component output="false" accessors="true" {

    property string title;

    public any function init() output = false {

        setTitle("");
        return this;

    }

}
```

Here, I never write the `setTitle()` setter, it's just implicit.

Is there any such thing for JavaScript (or even jQuery) in either ES5 / ES6 / ES7?

Comment: Can't you just do `title = "";`?

Comment: No, there is no such thing in jQuery, which is not a language extension but just a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign arbitrary properties to any object without explicitly writing setters/getters.

Although you can use them if you like.

```js
function myClass() {}

Object.defineProperty(myClass.prototype, "bar", {
  get: function get_bar() {
    return this._bar;
  },
  set: function set_bar(value) {
    this._bar = value;
    alert(value);
  }
});

var instance = new myClass();
instance.foo = "123"; // Arbitary
instance.bar = "456"; // Explicit setter/getter
console.log(instance.foo, instance.bar);
```

Comment: Just to note since this is tagged with ES6, there is an inline syntax for these now, ```class myClass {
  get bar(){ return this._bar; }
  set bar(value){ this._bar = value;}
}```